# Defined Value Giving: Object is possibly 'undefined'`. How to Avoid Manually Re-Asserting Types Using Zod

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-inference, zod

In this function, I am getting a type error from VS Code. The error refers to `board[0]`.  The error states `Object is possibly 'undefined'` which refers to`

```
export default function validPosition(board: Grid | Board, position: Position) {
  const [row, col] = position
  const numRows = board.length
  const numCols = board[0]?.length

  return row >= 0 && row < numRows && col >= 0 && col < numCols
}
```

I have these zod validators and inferred types

```
export const cellValidator = z.object({
  shown: z.boolean(),
  flagged: z.boolean(),
  mine: z.boolean(),
  numNeighbors: z.optional(z.number().nonnegative()),
})
export const gridValidator = z.array(z.array(z.number()).min(1)).min(1)
export const boardValidator = z.array(z.array(cellValidator).min(1)).min(1)
export const positionValidator = z.tuple([
  z.number().nonnegative(),
  z.number().nonnegative(),
])

export type Cell = z.infer<typeof cellValidator>
export type Grid = z.infer<typeof gridValidator>
export type Board = z.infer<typeof boardValidator>
export type Position = z.infer<typeof positionValidator>
```

I know that this error is incorrect, `board[0]` can never be undefined. `board` is an array and it will always have at minimum 1 entry, which is an array of `number` types. That inner array will also always have at least 1 entry of a `number` type, and I validated this with zod:

```
export const gridValidator = z.array(z.array(z.number()).min(1)).min(1)
export const boardValidator = z.array(z.array(cellValidator).min(1)).min(1)
```

I can satisfy the type checker in a few (hacky) ways:

```
(board[0] as Cell[] | Array<number>).length 

// or
board[0]!.length

// or
board[0]?.length
```

Each of these presents its own unique issues.

The bottom line is I shouldn't have to use my human brain to know the types and then manually reassert them through my codebase in order to satisfy the type checker. As I understand it, zod should carry this type inference through my code for me.

What is going on here? Why is the type checker saying that `board[0]` could possibly be undefined when (1) I know it is defined (2) I explicitly validated the fact that it will be defined with zod? What is a clean type-inferencey way to satisfy this type checker / TS error?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` enabled in your tsconfig.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess

Also, using zod to assert an array isn't empty doesn't change the fact the property is still an array, and TS will still add `| undefined` when trying to access an element if `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` is enabled.